# ExtJS / Javascript - Auto expand alert window height/wrap text text size

Tags: javascript, extjs, popup, alert

Looking for some advice on how I can have my alert window auto-expand when it displays the data in it.

The way the alert window works, when a row in my grid is double clicked, it displays the data stored in "command_output" in an alert window.

The issue I'm facing is sometimes the command_output can be 5000 characters long without any spaces in it. When the alert window pops up, it stays the default width and only shows the characters that fit on one line, the rest gets clipped off.

How can I have my alert window auto expand for height while wrapping the text?

I'm using ExtJS 5.0.1

[Popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JrYw.png)

```
    onDoubleClick: function(grid, record) {
    Ext.Msg.show({
        title : 'Copy the Dossier',
        msg : record.get('command_output'),
        closable : false,
        buttons : Ext.Msg.YESNO,
        buttonText : 
            {
                            yes : 'I copied the dossier - lets continue',
                            no : "Oops this isn't the dossier - lets go back"
            },
                    icon : Ext.Msg.INFO
                    });
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out using CSS.

**css**

```
.msg-wrap {
word-wrap: break-word !important;
white-space: normal !important;
```

}

**function**

```
onDoubleClick: function(grid, record) {
    Ext.Msg.show({
        xtype: 'panel',
        title : 'Copy the Dossier',
        message : record.get('command_output'),
        width: 600,
        cls: 'msg-wrap',
        buttons : Ext.Msg.YESNO,
        multiline: false,
        buttonText : 
            {
                            yes : 'I copied the dossier - lets continue',
                            no : "Oops this isn't the dossier - lets go back"
            },
                    icon : Ext.Msg.INFO
                    });
       }
```